# Save Excel Worksheet in Eclipse To Add To Java Project Apache Poi

Tags: java, excel, eclipse, apache-poi

I have a small java application, that takes two spreadsheets of miscellaneous data and creates one giant workbook with multiple sheets and organized data/equations etc, all in a nice, formatted workbook. I have created this in Eclipse using Apache POI.

I want to store a sheet in the actual program that is the "Main Overview Documentation" - Essentially a guide on how to read the rest of the sheets.

This overview will never change, so instead of writing/coding it in the program, I'd like to save the sheet in my actual source folder (if that's how I'm supposed to do it - I'd like to save in the application itself) - and attach the sheet to the beginning of my final workbook.

I am struggling even finding good searches to tell me how I do this.

Edit: Essentially I want to store a spreadsheet in the program that will not be edited, and in my application add that spreadsheet to my workbook that I have created

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to make a copy of your starter Excel document, then append the new sheets to that document.

This method for editing an existing file may be useful.  You'd just need to first clone the template document.

[Updating existing Excel file in Java Apache POI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31685244/updating-existing-excel-file-in-java-apache-poi)